# cakephp3 date_format error: Call to a member function format() on boolean FrozenTimeTrait.php

Tags: date-formatting, cakephp-3.x

**fnacimiento** and **ffallecimiento** is date in the table

```
$personas = TableRegistry::get('Personas')->find();
$personas = $personas->select([
              'fnacimiento' => 'date_format(fnacimiento, "%d/%m/%Y")',
              'ffallecimiento' => 'date_format(ffallecimiento, "%d/%m/%Y")']);
$this->set('personas', $personas);
```

I want to move from 0000-00-00 to 00/00/0000 (YYYY-MM-DD to DD/MM/YYYY)

But it is not working it gives me this error:

> Error: Call to a member function format() on boolean File
>   ...vendor/cakephp/chronos/src/Traits/FrozenTimeTrait.php Line: 161

The query is fine, because in mysql it works, but cakephp has some problem with the format, I do not understand it.

Comment: That sounds like something that should be done in the view layer, as it's most likely for presentation purposes. In any case, people won't really be able to help you here, as the rest of the relevant code, and the stacktrace (and ideally also the context and arguments) for the error are missing from your question, so it's impossible to tell where things might go wrong.

Comment: I have added information in the question.